# MudBlazor - Unable to change UI properties when initially set in OnAfterRenderAsync

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

What I am trying to achieve is quite simple. I want to be able to click a button, button goes off and does something, once the something is complete, the button changes colour. Complication arises because the button this applies to is in a MudDataGrid row. Thanks to another SO post, I have the following:

```
    <MudDataGrid Items="@PickList.PickListLines" Class="py-8 my-8">
        <Columns>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.SalesOrderRef" Title="Sales Order"/>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.LineNumber" Title="Line"/>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.ProductCode" Title="Product" />
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Quantity" Title="Qty" />
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.ItemType" Title="Type"/>
            <TemplateColumn CellClass="d-flex justify-end">
                <CellTemplate>
                    <MudButton @ref="_buttonRefs[context.Item.LineNumber]" Size="Size.Large" Variant="@Variant.Filled"  Class="@context.Item.LineNumber" OnClick="@(x => AddShortage(PickList.PickListId, context.Item.LineNumber))">Shortage</MudButton>
                </CellTemplate>
            </TemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MudDataGrid>
```

Then, in my code-behind, this:

```
    [Parameter]
public string PickListNumber { get; set; }
[Inject]
IInternalApiDataService InternalApiDataService { get; set; }

Dictionary<string, MudButton> _buttonRefs = new Dictionary<string, MudButton>();

public PickList PickList { get; set; } = new PickList();

protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    PickList = await InternalApiDataService.GetPickListAsync(PickListNumber);
}

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender == false)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MudButton> b in _buttonRefs)
        {
            b.Value.Color = Color.Primary;
            b.Value.StartIcon = Icons.Material.Filled.DoNotDisturb;
        }

    }

    StateHasChanged();

}

public async void AddShortage(string pickListNumber, string pickListLine)
{
    var x = await InternalApiDataService.RegisterShortageAsync(pickListNumber, Int32.Parse(pickListLine));

    var btn = _buttonRefs.First(x => x.Key == pickListLine).Value;

    btn.Color = Color.Tertiary;
    btn.StartIcon = Icons.Material.Filled.Check;

    StateHasChanged();
}
```

(I also had another version of the _buttonRefs.First which used TryGetValue which I have replaced). Here is my issue. If I comment out the code inside the OnAfterRenderAsync override, my button correctly changes colour when clicked. However with the OnAfterRender method in there, my buttons are correctly rendered in the desired colour and with the desired icon, but they no longer change when the OnClick handler fires...

I am sure this is a lifecycle issue, but I cannot figure out why. I have also tried removing the 'if(firstRender == false)' check to see if this changes things but it doesn't.

Interestingly, I notice when debugging that the OnAfterRenderAsync actually fires when the _buttonRefs dictionary is not yet initialised, which was also unexpected.

How do I need to structure this so that I can apply the colour and icon to the buttons, which is still correctly changed by the code in the OnClick event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call `StateHasChanged` inside *OnAfterRenderAsync*. This will cause a infinite render loop because *OnAfterRenderAsync* lifecycle event will be called every time **any** state changes & anytime `StateHasChanged` is called.
It should only be called in that lifecycle method if it's inside a controlled statement, e.g. inside an `if(firstRender)` block.

---

## Edit: The following solution is not recommend

As pointed out by @MrC in the comments, directly modifying the parameter of a component using it's `@ref` is bad because it bypasses the components Paramter setting process using `ParameterView` &  `SetParametersAsync` lifecycle event, probably more reasons but just this should be reason enough to not use this approach.

I recommend using [@MrC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77459069/11779494)

---

The problem here is that we only want to set the buttons to a default value **once** however `Dictionary<int, MudButton> _buttonRefs` will not be rendered in the *first render* of *OnAfterRenderAsync* it will have to be in the subsequent renders.

So we can introduce a local boolean to track when the buttons are rendered inside the *OnAfterRenderAsync* lifecycle. While making sure the `StateHasChanged` call inside the *OnAfterRenderAsync* method is controlled to only be called **once**.

Here's a demo [MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wYGdlvEMJlKdJujj)

**Note** I've intentionally made the demo verbose and added a `_renderCount` field just for debugging and is not required for this to work.

```cs
Dictionary<int, MudButton> _buttonRefs = new Dictionary<int, MudButton>();
bool _buttonsRendered = false;
int _renderCount = 0;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (_buttonsRendered == false)
    {
        _renderCount++;
        if(_buttonRefs.Count>0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Buttons rendered after:{_renderCount} render cycles");
            foreach (var b in _buttonRefs)
            {
                b.Value.Color = Color.Primary;
                b.Value.StartIcon = Icons.Material.Filled.DoNotDisturb;
            }
            _buttonsRendered = true;
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: RBee that's twice you have come to my rescue. Absolutely spot on, and I couldn't make sense of the fact that _buttonRefs was uninitialized the first time OnAftrerRender was firing. Found a good lifecycle doc which I think has cleared it up (I assume it is firing multiple times due to the component having one or more parents). Your solution works perfectly, and had I not been getting so frustrated I should have worked that out for myself!

Comment: No problem, I watch the mudblazor tag so likely to see me again if you have more mudblazor questions.

Comment: Nitpicking point but relevant - `OnAfterRenderAsync` is not part of the component lifecycle.  It's a UI event, just like a button click.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I don't mind learning, would it not make sense to have this logic in this event though? We need the DataGrid component to be rendered then apply the styling to the buttons.

Comment: Also the [Ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.onafterrender?view=aspnetcore-7.0#remarks) recommends using this lifecycle method to interact with values received from @ref.

Comment: MS Docs are good, but not the bible, and not always perfect.

Comment: @RBee - I think in this instance the design isn't correct.  Store the state against an identity for the row in a list/dictionary and then call a method to get the right parameter values.  `b.Value.Color = Color.Primary;` looks like it's setting a parameter directly from code which is not advised.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis hmm I don't quite follow what you're recommending, do you mean modifying the Button component itself (3rd party component). And yes, the  `Color` parameter for the button is being changed directly in code, why is that not advisable?

Comment: See my answer for more detail on changing the logic.  It does away with the need for `@ref`.

Comment: And see this MS Docs article on setting parameters - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/overwriting-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis The article you linked only mentions avoiding overwriting parameters in the child component that the parameter is declared, which makes sense because parent components will/are meant to override them. But I don't see how modifying parameters in the parent component in code section is an issue, even changing in the html section is essentially changing parameters in code.

Comment: @RBee - I respectfully beg to differ.  `b.Value.Color = Color.Primary;` - where `b` is the key/value pair, `Value` is the Button component reference and `Color` is the property - is setting the property directly.  That totally bypasses the Renderer's component `Parameter` setting process through `SetParametersAsync` where the parameter is passed in through the `ParameterView` object` and `ParameterView,SetParameterProperties` sets the properties.

Comment: The whole `OnAfterRender` process in the question mutates the Parameter state, and creates an inconsistency between the Renderer's `ParameterView` and the actual state of the component. That is why it's wrong.  In my answer there's no inconsistency, which is why I've provided it.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Ok I understand now, I did some [testing](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/zqe6nu99) and you're right, directly modifying using the `@ref` approach does seem to mess up the Parameter setting process, which is bound to cause unexpected behaviours.

Comment: @RBee - thanks for the acknowledgement.  Appreciated, and glad you've learned something.  Take if from an old man, never stop learning!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I appreciate that you took the time to directly (learnt a lot from your other answers) teach me this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I know you already have an answer, but your code contains a few issues that the answer does not address.

1. You are getting a reference to a component and then setting `Parameters` directly.  Parameters should be have a simple `{get; set;}` pattern.  If you change them outside the `SetParametersAsync` cycle, you have an inconsistency between the actual component parameter state and the Renderer's version.  This will lead to unexpected UI behaviour.
2. Your calling `StateHasChanged` in `OnAfterRender` which kicks off another render.

Here's a refactored version of your code (hopefully with close to the right application logic) that used the identity field for the row in place of capturing the buttons with `@ref`.

My shortened data objects:

```cs
public record PickItems(int LineNumber, string Description, int Quantity);

public class PickList
{
    public int PickListId { get; } = 1;

    private List<PickItems> _items = new()
        {
            new(1, "Squash", 10 ),
            new(2, "Bread", 16 ),
            new(3, "Oranges", 12 ),
            new(4, "Potatoes", 21 ),
       };

    public IEnumerable<PickItems> PickListLines => _items.AsEnumerable();
}
```

And then my version of your page.  I've added a bit of button functionality - disabling etc - to show how you can do that.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<MudDataGrid Items="@_pickList.PickListLines" Class="py-8 my-8">
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.LineNumber" Title="Line" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Description" Title="Product" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Quantity" Title="Qty" />
        <TemplateColumn CellClass="d-flex justify-end">
            <CellTemplate>
                <MudButton Size="Size.Large"
                           Variant="@Variant.Filled"
                           StartIcon="@this.GetIcon(context.Item.LineNumber)"
                           Disabled="this.IsDisabled(context.Item.LineNumber)"
                           Color="this.GetColor(context.Item.LineNumber)"
                           OnClick="() => this.AddShortage(_pickList.PickListId, context.Item.LineNumber)">
                    Shortage
                </MudButton>
            </CellTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>

@code {
    private bool _processing;
    private PickList _pickList = new PickList();
    private readonly List<int> _processedLines = new();

    private Color GetColor(int line)
    {
        if (_processedLines.Contains(line))
            return Color.Primary;

        return Color.Tertiary;
    }

    private string? GetIcon(int line)
    {
        if (_processedLines.Contains(line))
            return Icons.Material.Filled.DoDisturb;

        return null;
    }

    private bool Processed(int line)
        => _processedLines.Contains(line);

    private bool IsDisabled(int line)
        => this.Processed(line) || this._processing;

    private async Task AddShortage(int PickList, int LineNumber)
    {
        if (_processedLines.Contains(LineNumber))
        {
            // deal with it
            return;
        }

        _processing = true;
        //fake the api calls
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        _processedLines.Add(LineNumber);
        _processing = false;
    }
}
```

Everything is now built into the normal component lifecycle logic.

Comment: This is certainly one way to solve the problem, however unless there is a major flaw in using the @ref of the button to change parameters, I believe the latter solution provides more functionality.

Comment: The major flaw in the @Ref/OnAfterRender solution is that it creates a component state inconsistency.  The Renderer believes that `Color` is `null`, while in reality it's `Color.Primary`.   Inconsistencies are dangerous because they often lead to unpredictable behaviour.  It may "work" this time, but it's not a practice to replicate.